# How to show each object in a string

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to generate an string with all items from array but shows me [object Object].

How can I solve it?

Here is my code:

```
let geojson = '{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[';
let items = Object.values(table).slice();
items.forEach( item => {
  geojson += item;
});
geojson += ']}';
console.log(geojson);
```

SOLVE IT:

```
let geojson = '{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[';
let items = Object.values(table).slice();
items.forEach( item => {
  geojson += JSON.stringify(item);
});
geojson += ']}';
console.log(geojson);
```

And shows me this:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[[object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object][object Object]]}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Feel free to delete it if you solved it

Comment: Create an object like: `let obj = {"type":"FeatureCollection","features": Object.values(table) }` and call `JSON.stringify(obj)`

Comment: As adiga sugggest, I would prefer `let geo = { type: "featureCollection", features: Object.values( table ) }; let geojson = JSON.stringify( geo );`. Manually constructing a JSON string and having to account for things like individually stringifying objects as you show here, just feels like working from the end to the start to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{type:"FeatureCollection",features: Object.values(table)}
```